# How to "insert or update" depending on condition like "where room="living" and garden ="green" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

i would like to update a row if some fields have specific values ('id' isn't clear at this point) or to insert, if this combination is complete new.
Is it possible without a procedure and if so, how?
I think it somehow works with "on conflict" but i cant figure it out.
Thanks

Example:

`UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2,  WHERE column1 = 1 and column2 = 2;`

if there is no dataset where column1 = 1 and column2 = 2 do this:

`INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, column4) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, value4);`

Is it possible to realise this with just one query?

Comment: Ask again when you have clear, specific requirements.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i hope with my example it's now clear.

Comment: your update doesn't make sense to me as you are modifying the columns that are also used to find the rows in the WHERE clause. Did you mean to update `column3` and `column4` in the UPDATE statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You need a unique index or constraint on `(column1, column2)` then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, column4) 
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, value4)
on conflict (column1, column2) 
  do update 
    set column3 = excluded.column3, 
        column4 = excluded.column4;
```

Comment: You mean the value of column1 and column2 must be unique? But they arent unique, the combination of makes them unique thats the problem...

Comment: @PeterFox: that's what a unique constraint on `(column1, column2)` will achieve